# EXCEL ADVANCED MATCHING

Tags: excel

if i want to match cells in a different columns with condition as follows

```
cell A     CELL B
5.00        5.00    
1.00        5.00
8.00        5.00
5.00        6.00
```

Here cell A  value 5.00 has two times Only should match(highlight) match cell B only TWO TIME

Comment: unclear what the output is here. What rows should be highlighted? Do you just want to highlight the adjacent cell every time you see `5.00` in Column A? Or is all of this really inside a single cell?

Comment: MATCH($A3,$B$1:$B$10,0) if i use this ,the cell B high lite all 5.00 in the cell B .. I need a result like this cell A Has only 2 numbers 5.00 so select only 2 number of 5.00 from cell B          If cell A has only one 5 highlite only one 5 from cell B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this formula in conditional formatting.

```
=AND(COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,$B1)<=COUNTIF($A:$A,$B1),$B1<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: great correct answer i got thank you so much

Comment: @muhammedpalollathil if this worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark beside the answer.